# Python feed.parser get error 10060

Tags: python, rss

I run the command:

```
feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss') 
print    feed
```

and get the error message:

```
{'feed': {}, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'bozo': 1, 'version': None, 'entries': [], 'bozo_exception': URLError(error(10060, 'Operation timed out'),)}
```

I can get the page in IE.

Did any one encountered this problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: You're not behind a firewall or something corporate that would block access?

Comment: (If this is the case IE will work fine because the support guys will have configured a proxy)

Comment: Yes there is a FW of McAfee.

Comment: You will need to configure the feedparser to deal with the proxy too then. Try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031969/not-able-to-parse-rss-feeds

Comment: I tryed the solution and now i get the error message:{'feed': {}, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'bozo': 1, 'version': None, 'entries': [], 'bozo_exception': InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: 'port'",)}

Comment: What have you specified for the port? It seems like you're using a string rather than a number